# Asian movie from alternate reality with Tesla coil in Tokyo

Tags: story-identification, movie, soft-sci-fi

A friend of mine saw a movie some time ago on the TV, but he can't recall the name. Here is the description he gives:

> Japanese or Chinese movie, in the end, there was a Tesla coil (or some device for wireless transfer of electricity) in a skyscraper in Tokyo, which somebody wanted to use to destroy other cities. I am not 100% sure about the rest, but I think it was set in an alternative reality where Japan has won WW2

Any idea what movie could he be referring to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably *[K-20: Legend of the Mask](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1156395/?ref_=ttls_li_tt)*

> It's a classic action mystery which like The Prestige has Russian scientist Teslar providing the object of tussle, a device capable of harnessing and transmitting vast electrical power across locations without the use of cables. K-20 wants it to rule the world, and it's up to our heroes to crack the mystery as to where the device is, and to stop the villain from achieving his goal. The plot's fairly simple, which includes an origin story for Heikichi including the antics of a hero in training, but what made it palatable was the excellent delivery by the cast, together with gorgeous sets and edge-of-your-seat action. A key element here too is the identity of K-20, having nobody actually seen the villain in the flesh except for Heikichi himself.

[image: *K-20* movie poster]

### Trailer

Searching for *japanese film "tesla coil"* brought up this [list of films involving Nikola Tesla](https://www.imdb.com/list/ls056527127/) and the mention of an alternate history caught my eye.